# Submitting in Java in SPOJ

Tags: java

I tried submitting a program with many classes in Java , but SPOJ did not accept it by showing some compilation errors . How to submit multi class programs in java in SPOJ

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be so kind as to at least add the mentioned compilation errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can submit multi class Java programs to SPOJ.

Just define them as inner classes of your Main class.

Note that your inner class(es) do not necessarily need to be static.

Find below a SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example):

```
public class Main {

    static class One {
        static int getValue() {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    static class Two {
        static int getValue() {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    static class Calculator {
        static void printResult() {
            int sum = One.getValue() + Two.getValue();
            System.out.println("The sum is " + sum + ".");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator.printResult();
    }

}
```

> **Output:** The sum is 3.